# Recursion, using ArrayLists, is not recurring

Tags: java, recursion, for-loop, arraylist

I was busy with Problem 151 from projecteuler, http://projecteuler.net/problem=151, when I came across this issue.

I'm trying to make a simple recursion with an ArrayList `envelope` (which contains only powers of 2) and an int `index` as parameters. It first replaces the integer at position `index` of the envelope with all powers of 2 below it (e.g. 16 becomes 8,4,2,1). Then it loops the index from 0 to the end of the new `envelope` and applies the same recursion with the new envelope and the new index as parameters, until the envelope is equal to {1}. Let's say I'm counting the number of ways that this can be done. This is the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Prob151 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    totalCount = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(8);
    recursion(list,0,1);
    System.out.printf("%d",totalCount);
}

public static int totalCount;

public static void recursion(ArrayList<Integer> envelope, int index, int batch) {
    int number = envelope.get(index); 
    if (envelope.size() == 1 && number == 1) {

        totalCount += 1;

    } else {

        // Updates the envelope
        envelope.remove(index);
        while (number > 1) {
            number /= 2;
            envelope.add(number);
        }
        batch += 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < envelope.size(); i++) {
            // Displays current information
            System.out.printf("batch = %d, envelope = {",batch);
            for (int j : envelope) {
                System.out.printf("%d,",j);
            }
            System.out.printf("}, i = %d\n",i);

            recursion(envelope,i,batch);
        }

    }
}

}
```

This was the output that I got:

```
batch = 2, envelope = {4,2,1,}, i = 0
batch = 3, envelope = {2,1,2,1,}, i = 0
batch = 4, envelope = {1,2,1,1,}, i = 0
batch = 5, envelope = {2,1,1,}, i = 0
batch = 6, envelope = {1,1,1,}, i = 0
batch = 7, envelope = {1,1,}, i = 0
batch = 8, envelope = {1,}, i = 0
1
```

Instead of going back to batch 7 with index i = 1, it just stops after it encounters the first instance where envelope = {1}. What should I change in order to get the required result?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing a copy of an envelope to recursive call instead of sharing one envelope between all levels? ` recursion(envelope.clone(),i,batch);` ? Now when you are returning to the level 7 envelope size is 1.

Comment: I've changes envelope to (ArrayList<Integer>) envelope.clone() and it's working perfectly now :)

Answer (score 0):

A few things to help you here:

1)  You are using the wrong data structure, the problem clearly states he grabs an envelope at random.  I highly recommend the use of a `Bag`.

2)  After the first batch is run your envelope contains the following elements:

```
1 A2    
1 A3  
1 A4  
1 A5
```

So the odds of picking A5 on the first pass are `1 in 4`,  so if it fails to find the `A5` on the first selection and we get `A2` your envelope looks like this:

```
2 A3  
2 A4  
2 A5
```

Now the third batch has a `2 in 6` (1 in 3) chance of selecting an `A5` .

Let me know if this clarification needs more explanation.

Comment: This is not actually my original code. In my original code, I'm keeping track of the probability that a certain series of cuts can occur by multiplying 1/(size of the envelope at the current batch). And I'm also keeping track of the number of times that there is a single element in the envelope. But since that isn't where my problem is, I've left that out and simplified it.